# How to revert "Never translate this site" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, translation

I visited a foreign website and I accidentally clicked "Never translate this site". I want to revert this back to the default behavior of Chrome always asking me what to do. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24):

Corrected my answer as pointed out.

### First Method

- Go to the webpage you want translated
- Bring up context menu via right-click
- Click translate to "your default language"

### Second Method

- Go to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
- Open Preferences with a text editor
- Search `translate_site_blacklist`
- Find and delete url of the page you want translated  `"translate_site_blacklist":["page you want translated","some other url","one another"],`
- After edits it should look exactly like this : `"translate_site_blacklist":[""]`

These will translate the page and / or reset your settings for that page.

Comment: That's not what the OP intended, your answer indicates you can change the languages which are suggested or disable this feature. There's no option to undo a "never translate" choice.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake. it was a misunderstanding on my side. i  corrected the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted, some people lack the interest in positive feedback. In anycase, that's also what I was thinking so +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but it didn't work. I edited the file by removing every value after the colon, so the end result is "translate_site_blacklist":,"SYNTAX", and then I fired up Chrome. It said that the preference file is corrupted and can't be recovered, and it restores itself back to its default settings - and logs me out. To get my settings and data back, I have to log-in - and that's stage I guess the preferences file reverts itself back to its pre-edit state. When I enter that website, it is shown in its original language with no popup offering me translation.

Comment: you just have to delete  "page you want translated",  part. not more than that. (including " and , )

Comment: So this is how it shoudl appear? "translate_site_blacklist":[""],

Comment: Yes it is, btw didn't first method work for you?

Comment: 1. Regarding the first method: I'm not sure where should I right-click to evoke that specific context menu. I've clicked everywhere possible but no context menu show a relevant option. 2. In the Preferences file, should I leave the brackets after the [code]"translate_site_blacklist":[/code]?

Comment: i've edited my answer to show how it should look like after edits.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the file exactly like you said, but it still doesn't work. It seems that when I start Chrome for the first time after the editing, the Preferences file is reverted by the system back to its pre-edit version.

Comment: Help? Anyone? The mileage required to offset such a user-generated error is ridiculous, on Google's part...

Comment: The second method seems outdated. I wasn't able to find that file.

Answer (score 22):

1. Open Chrome on the device that has the problem (smartphone, computer, tablet)
2. Enter this address: `chrome://about`
3. Click `chrome://translate-internals`
4. In `Untranslated sites` delete the site that does not offer the translation of pages

Note: Must be done for each device that presented the problem (smartphone, computer, tablet).

Comment: The accepted answer (right click -> translate page) is the easiest way to answer the original question, but this page is awesome and I wish I'd known about it sooner.

Answer (score 2):

new chrome is a bit different, these work:

Open Chrome on the device that has the problem (smartphone, computer, tablet)

Enter this address: chrome://about

Click chrome://translate-internals

but now you just click the X next to the site you want to revert to (translate, never translate, always translate)

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. I've made a mistake and for a Chinese side selected never translate; even though, now I fixed it, but I really don't know which one of my works made it.

1. I selected 'Settings', in 'Advanced Settings' I chose 'Language' and then removed all languages, then reselected 'English' and some other languages.
2. I've opened a Chinese site and selected (•••) above of the page and selected (translate ...) Option.

Since that, on Chinese sites, it always asks for translate!!